# how to compare the list of numbers to a predefined value and output the index of that value

Tags: python

I have 2 lists, `A= [ 18.0, 25.6, 35.6, 36.6,2.0]` and `B=[ root, init, top, cpu, mem]` both are of length 5.

I want to compare the elements of A are greater than 30.0 or not.
And want to output all the elements which are greater than 30 in A.
Also output the index of those elements along with the entry at same index number in B

I am new to python and hence want to learn how to compare elements of list to a number..
If i am using

```
For i in A:
       If i > 30
      print A[i]
```

But its showing me syntax error.

Please help me with the code.

Comment: `for` and `if` are lowercase and you need a colon after 30, and further indentation of `print`

Comment: In python u dont require colons right?

Comment: Where did you get that idea from?

Comment: On further though, I think you might be referring to _semi-colons_ which are not required at the end of lines, but you still require colons at the end of `for` and `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(A)):
    if A[i] > 30:
        print("Value" + str(A[i]) + " Index " + str(i) + " Table B Value " + str(B[i]) )
```

Comment: While this works, it is not very Pythonic. Iterating over the index of a list is something done in C.

Comment: This is just printing the same list.  Its nore comparing whether its greater than 30 or not.. Below 30 values are also printed

Comment: @AnketPadwalkar Are you kidding? There is a big comparison `> 30` which is what you want. Are you sure you run the code of Ira?

Comment: No i have copied the same code.. It is printing all the values of A and all the values of B aswell

Answer (score 0):

This can be one lined:

```
pairs = {key: value for key, value in zip(A,B) if key > 30.0}
print(pairs)
```

This is called a dict comperhension, you may read more about it on : [Python Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

Comment: "output the index of those elements"

Answer (score 0):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)  the [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)ed lists.

```
a = [ 18.0, 25.6, 35.6, 36.6,2.0]
b = ["root", "init", "top", "cpu", "mem"]
for i, pair in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    if pair[0] > 30.0:
        print("i={}, a={}, b={}".format(i, pair[0], pair[1]))
```

Output:

```
i=2, a=35.6, b=top
i=3, a=36.6, b=cpu
```

Comment: It doesn't show the output which u have mentioned. Its just displaying the combination of 2 lists.  it is not comparing it to.30.  It prints every entry

Comment: Well, then you must have made some mistake copy/pasting my code. Just try it a it is, it works.

Comment: @LutzHorn my only guess is that they are actually running P2.7 and the list contains strings, not floats. The example list of strings is also missing inverted commas.

Comment: @roganjosh Well, the list `B` from the question contains names. But I am not inclined to guess.

Comment: Yeah, that's fair enough, but you can always try `if float(pair[0]) > 30.0:`. And they could be names, true, but I would say that getting such a list is a step beyond the basic syntax that they are struggling with.

Comment: I have copied the same code which u have given.. But all the values it is printing with respective entry in next list

Comment: @AnketPadwalkar As I said: you must be doing something wrong.

Comment: If i try adding float..  Its showing me syntax error

Comment: @AnketPadwalkar there is no way you could get a syntax error on that if you copied it correctly. I really don't think we're going to be able to solve this issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [18.0, 25.6, 35.6, 36.6, 2.0]
B = ['root', 'init', 'top', 'cpu', 'mem']
zipped = zip(A, B)

i = 0
for k, v in zipped:
    if k > 30.0: 
         print("index: {}, valueFromA: {}, valueFromB: {}".format(i, k, v))
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
index: 2, valueFromA: 35.6, valueFromB: top
index: 3, valueFromA: 36.6, valueFromB: cpu
```

Comment: `zipped` is what? And using a loop index `i` is not Pythonic.

Comment: @LutzHorn True, but knowing why it should be Pythonic takes time